# create custom query for liferay default table

Tags: java, liferay

I want to know if it's possible to create custom query for liferay default table like user, userGroup...

I looked at the [example](https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-0/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/custom-sql) but they give examples that on the custom tables (guestbook table)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
public List<User>  getUserByRecentChat(long userId){

    Session session=null;
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) PortalBeanLocatorUtil.locate("liferaySessionFactory");
    try {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        String sql = CustomSQLUtil.get(getClass(), "getUserByRecentChat");
        SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
        sqlQuery.setCacheable(false);

        sqlQuery.addEntity("users_", UserImpl.class); // for user table

        QueryPos pos = QueryPos.getInstance(sqlQuery);
        pos.add(userId);
        pos.add(userId);
        return (List<User>) sqlQuery.list();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        sessionFactory.closeSession(session);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use Custom Query for Liferay Default Tables

Thanks

Comment: How can i use custom query?  When i create UserGroupFInderImpl and i run the service builder the userGroupFinder interface is not generated. And I created the class UserGroupLocalServiceOverride which extends from UserGroupLocalServiceWrapper to use my custom query, I use UserGroupFinder but this interface does not contain my method finder

Comment: You could probably just create finder for custom impl as in your case GuestFinderImpl  and in that u can have your query for Liferay Default Table.